# Limitation of number of pages in elastic search to 100

Tags: elasticsearch

In the elasticsearch, there are 8000 results. I need to get 10 results per page. It means there are 800 pages should be. However, I can only get 100 pages because of the elastic search limitation issue. Is there a way to increase that?

Comment: I am not aware of such a limitation, which version are you running ? What error do you get ?

Comment: I am using ELK app server to configure the requirements.
(Bad Request) is the error